# Bootstrap Collapse.js Switch Hide/Show for menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having trouble with bootstraps collapse. I have 2 menu items, with a dropdown collapse. I'm trying to alternate/switch them so I DONT get to see both at the same time. I've tried using `'toggle:false'` but that does't seem to be working with bootstrap.

Please see the [codepen](http://codepen.io/moletek/pen/bpKvdX) for a working demonstration. Currently am using `data-` tags to create the functionality.

I'm wondering whether the DOM treats the collapse functionality as 2 separate things and therefore doesn't correlate them together.

So I have

```
<div class="search-bar>...</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">...</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseFilter">...</div>
```

Inside the search bar I have 2 anchor elements which trigger the collapse. And then a non-related drop-down.

```
 <a id="search-button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample">
    <span class="icon-search"></span>Search
 </a> <!--Simplified -->
```

So I'm not sure why BOTH dropdown collapse elements come down. I want it to work just like the [accordion style](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force hiding other menu like this:

```
$("#search-button").click(function() {
    $('#collapseFilter').collapse('hide');
});

$("#filter-button").click(function() {
    $('#collapseExample').collapse('hide');
});
```

See [***JsFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/zkfe7tvb/) of your demonstration. *I hope it helps, Thanks*